# thread and handler call different methods each time

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on app which communicate the web server. I want two methods which call by thread and also need two handler method, which used to update UI . 1 thread method and handler method need to fetch data and update UI at start of the activity. 2 thread method and handler method need to post back data on server.
How I implement this.

My code of this class...

```
 package com.edoc.doctor;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import com.edoc.libraries.FetchMedicines;
 import com.edoc.libraries.Functions;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.Message;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class AddPatient extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener
 {
    public static final String appDoctor = "AppDoctor";

    public String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";

     private String success;

    private ProgressDialog pd;
     private JSONObject jsonObj;

    private boolean addNewPatient;

    private EditText email;
    private EditText phone;
    private EditText name;
    private EditText dob;
    private EditText lowBPMedicineInstructions;
    private EditText highBPMedicineInstructions;
    private EditText hyperLowBPMedicineInstructions;
    private EditText hyperHighBPMedicineInstructions;

    private Spinner lowBPMedicine;
    private Spinner highBPMedicine;
    private Spinner hyperLowBPMedicine;
    private Spinner hyperHighBPMedicine;

    private Button addPatient;


    private String strEmail;
    private String strPhone;
    private String strName;
    private String strDob;
    private String strLowBPMedicineInstructions;
    private String strHighBPMedicineInstructions;
    private String strHyperLowBPMedicineInstructions;
    private String strHyperHighBPMedicineInstructions;

     private String strLowBPMedicine;
private String strHighBPMedicine;
private String strHyperLowBPMedicine;
private String strHyperHighBPMedicine;

private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> medicines;
private ArrayList<Integer> medicineIDs;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_patient);

    medicines = new ArrayList<String>();
    medicineIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    addPatient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ib_add_patient);
    addPatient.setOnClickListener(this);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_add_patient_email);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_add_patient_phone);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_add_patient_name);
    dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_add_patient_date_of_birth);

    lowBPMedicineInstructions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_low_description);
    highBPMedicineInstructions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_high_description);
    hyperLowBPMedicineInstructions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_hyper_low_description);
    hyperHighBPMedicineInstructions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iet_hyper_high_description);

    lowBPMedicine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.isp_low_medicine);
    highBPMedicine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.high_medicine);
    hyperLowBPMedicine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hyper_low_medicine);
    hyperHighBPMedicine = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hyper_high_medicine);

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, medicines);

    final int did = getID();
//  pd = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Working..", "Connect To Server", true,false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    { 
        public void run()
        {
            Functions fun = new Functions();
            jsonObj = fun.fetchMedicines(did);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
}).start();


}
private Handler handler = new Handler() 
{


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {

        try {
            Log.e("try","try");
            success = jsonObj.getString("success");

            Log.e("success",success);
            Log.e("add",""+addNewPatient);
            if(success.equals("1") && !addNewPatient)
            {
                JSONArray m = jsonObj.getJSONArray("medicines");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < m.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = m.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = c.getString("medicine");
                    int id = c.getInt("id");
                    Log.e("m name",name+" "+id);
                    medicines.add(name);
                    medicineIDs.add(id);
                }


                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                lowBPMedicine.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                highBPMedicine.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                hyperLowBPMedicine.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                hyperHighBPMedicine.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            }
            else if(success.equals("1") && addNewPatient)
            {
                Log.e("success", ""+addNewPatient);
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Patient Add Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server down",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};


public int getID()
{
    int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(appDoctor,mode);
    Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    return mySharedPreferences.getInt("id",0);
}
@Override
public void run() 
{
    Functions function = new Functions();   
    jsonObj = function.addPatient(strEmail,strPhone,strName,strDob,strLowBPMedicine
            ,strHighBPMedicine,strHyperHighBPMedicine,strHyperLowBPMedicine,strLowBPMedicineInstructions
            , strHighBPMedicineInstructions, strHyperLowBPMedicineInstructions, strHyperHighBPMedicineInstructions, getID());
    addNewPatient = true;
    Log.e("run", ""+addNewPatient);
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Log.e("onclick","on click");

    strEmail = email.getText().toString();
    strPhone = phone.getText().toString();
    strName = name.getText().toString();
    strDob = dob.getText().toString();

    strLowBPMedicine = ""+lowBPMedicine.getSelectedItemPosition();
    strHighBPMedicine = ""+highBPMedicine.getSelectedItemPosition();
    strHyperLowBPMedicine = ""+hyperLowBPMedicine.getSelectedItemPosition();
    strHyperLowBPMedicine = ""+hyperLowBPMedicine.getSelectedItemPosition();

    strLowBPMedicineInstructions = lowBPMedicineInstructions.getText().toString();
    strHighBPMedicineInstructions = highBPMedicineInstructions.getText().toString();
    strHyperLowBPMedicineInstructions = hyperLowBPMedicineInstructions.getText().toString();
    strHyperHighBPMedicineInstructions = hyperHighBPMedicineInstructions.getText().toString();

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Connect To Server", true,false);
    Thread t = new Thread();
    t.start();
}

  }
```

This stuck on line 222 
form below 3rd statement.
     pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Connect To Server", true,false);

Comment: @Ahmar: you will get much better response from the community if you show what you have so far and where it your stumbling block. Be concise and as specific as possible.

Comment: I add the class code.